# Cakephp. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CalendarsClassification.id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

When I delete a classification, I get this error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CalendarsClassification.id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `CalendarsClassification`.`id` FROM `calendars_classifications` AS `CalendarsClassification` WHERE `CalendarsClassification`.`calendar_id` = 221
```

`CalendarsClassification`.`id` does not exist, but I do not know how to change it.

ClassificationsController

```
    public function delete($id = null) {        
    if (!$id) {
        $this->flash(__('Invalid Classification', true), array('controller'=>'clients','action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->request->data = $this->Classification->read(null, $id);
    if ($this->Classification->delete($id, true)) {
        $this->flash(__('Classificació esborrada.', true), array('controller'=>'blocks','action'=>'view',$this->data['Classification']['block_id']));
    }
}
```

Model Classification

```
class Classification extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Classification';
var $validate = array(
    'long_name' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 1)
    )
);

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Block' => array('className' => 'Block',
                            'foreignKey' => 'block_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
        )
);
var $hasMany = array(
        'Line' => array('className' => 'Line',
                            'foreignKey' => 'classification_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'dependent' => true,
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
);

var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Calendar' => array('className' => 'Calendar',  
                       'joinTable'    => 'calendars_classifications',
                       'foreignKey'   => 'calendar_id',
                       'associationForeignKey'=> 'classification_id',
                       'conditions'   => '',
                       'fields' => '',
                       'order'        => '',
                       'limit'        => '',
                       'unique'       => true,
                       'finderQuery'  => '',
                       'deleteQuery'  => '',
         )
 );
```

}

Comment: `id` field exist in `CalendarsClassification` table..?

Comment: Try this $this->Classification->delete(array('CalendarsClassification.calendar_id' => $id), false);

Answer (score 1):

if there is the field 'id' in the table and still you are unable to delete the row then you should clear the cache and then try to delete the row.

here is the path for cache:
\app\tmp\cache\models

and

\app\tmp\cache\persistent

Note: Do not delete the folder.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i believe it should be "calendar_id" instead of "id".
As per the Query reflects.

SELECT `CalendarsClassification`.`id` FROM `calendars_classifications` AS `CalendarsClassification` WHERE `CalendarsClassification`.`calendar_id` = 221

Answer (score 0):

If you're table doesn't have a column `id` then you need to [define which column is the primary key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) in the relevant model. For example:-

```
class CalendarsClassification extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = 'example_id';

}
```

The model `delete()` method uses the primary key as the first parameter to delete with so you must set the `primaryKey` for the model if it is different from Cake conventions before using this method.

You really should have a primary key for every model and it is advisable to stick with Cake conventions and name it `id` if possible as this will simplify your code significantly.

If you are not trying to delete a record by the primary key then you want to be using `deleteAll()` for which you can pass conditions for the deletion as the first parameter. Something like this:-

```
$this->CalendarsClassification->deleteAll(['example_id' => $id]);
```